# How to insert bookmark in Word using Python (win32com)?

Tags: python, ms-word, bookmarks, win32com

I am using win32com, how can I insert a bookmark with an existing text in the Word Document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import win32com.client
wordApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application') # alternately DispatchEx
wordApp.visible = True                                 # alternately False or leave out
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open('c:/my_word_doc.docx')
myRange = wordDoc.Content
myRange.Find.Execute(FindText='peanuts')
myRange.Bookmarks.Add(Name='X')
wordDoc.SaveAs('c:/my_word_doc.docx')
wordDoc.Close()
wordApp.Quit()
```

If you don't want Word to be visible during this process use `win32com.client.DispatchEx` and don't set `wordApp.visible` to `True`.

Comment: Thank you ! But I want to create a bookmark for a text present in my Document, how can I select it and then create a bookmark from it ?

For example, in my Word Document there is this phrase : 
I like peanuts.

And I want to create a bookmark named "X" where the Selection is "peanuts".

Comment: Ah now I see your question says that.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express myself well. Thank you !